# Use 'loc' to select multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set of news with 3 columns: `lead_paragraph`, `_id`, `web_url`.

The following code returns a row matching the id along with News `lead_paragraph`.

```py
ds = pd.read_csv("nytimes.csv")
def item(id):
    return ds.loc[ds['_id'] == id]['lead_paragraph'].tolist()[0]
```

How to get `web_url` also with `lead_paragraph` in the list?

Got an error after trying one solution

```
return ds.loc[ds['_id'] == id], ['web_url', 'lead_paragraph']].tolist()
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `df.loc[ds['_id'] == id], ['x', 'y', 'z']].tolist()[0]`

Comment: return [ds['_id'] == id], ['lead_paragraph','web_url']].tolist()[0] 
Its giving syntax error @coldspeed

Comment: @ScottBoston syntax error

Comment: ` return ds.loc[ds['_id'] == id], ['lead_paragraph','web_url' ] ].tolist()[0] `
Syntax error again

Comment: Can you paste the full error to the question.

Comment: Sorry, it is `ds.loc[ds['_id'] == id, ['x', 'y', 'z']].tolist()[0]`

Comment: @coldspeed ok let me try

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [df.loc[*row indexer*, *columns indexer*]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data),

```
df.loc[df['_id'] == id, ['web_url', 'lead_paragraph']].values[0].tolist()
```

Where *row indexer* is a boolean series and *column indexer* is a list of column labels.

Comment: return ds.loc[ds['_id'] == id], ['lead_paragraph','web_url']].tolist()[0] 
its giving me syntax error

Comment: You are correct, there was an extra ] before the first comma.

Comment: Can i refer my whole code , so that you can see what i am trying to do